# Understanding Deadlock graph on one table

Tags: sql-server-2005, deadlock

I do not understand this deadlock graph that we are experiencing on this table (I have had to redact the exact column names) I have not had much exposure to deadlocks outside of reading material and this doesn't fit my basic understanding of a deadlock and after several hours chasing information online I am none the wiser

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table](
[ColumnID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[2ColumnID] [int] NOT NULL,
[3Column] [int] NOT NULL,
[4Column] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
[5Column] [char](4) NULL,
[6Column] [varchar](max) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_TableName] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ColumnID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,  
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 10) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Here is the SQl Error Log

```
10/04/2013 17:07:40 spid4s      Deadlock encountered .... Printing deadlock information                                                                                                                                                                                                    
10/04/2013 17:07:40 spid4s      Wait-for graph                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
10/04/2013 17:07:40 spid4s                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
10/04/2013 17:07:40 spid4s      Node:1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
10/04/2013 17:07:40 spid4s      OBJECT: 6:1629964883:0         CleanCnt:3 Mode:SIX    Flags: 0x0                                                                                                                                                                                              
10/04/2013 17:07:40 spid4s       Grant List 0:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
10/04/2013 17:07:40 spid4s       Grant List 1:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
10/04/2013 17:07:40 spid4s       Grant List 2:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
10/04/2013 17:07:40 spid4s         Owner:0x0000000087AC0100 Mode: SIX      Flg:0x0 Ref:3 Life:02000000 SPID:82 ECID:0 XactLockInfo: 0x0000000162F99388                                                                                                                                     
10/04/2013 17:07:40 spid4s         SPID: 82 ECID: 0 Statement Type: DELETE Line #: 1                                                                                                                                                                                                       
10/04/2013 17:07:40 spid4s         Input Buf: Language Event: (@p0 int,@p1 int,@p2 int,@p3 varchar(16),@p4 char(4))DELETE FROM [dbo].[Table] WHERE ([ColumnID] = @p0) AND ([2ColumnID] = @p1) AND ([3Column] = @p2) AND ([4Column] = @p3) AND ([5Column] = @p4)                    
10/04/2013 17:07:40 spid4s       Grant List 3:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
10/04/2013 17:07:40 spid4s       Requested By:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
10/04/2013 17:07:40 spid4s         ResType:LockOwner Stype:'OR'Xdes:0x0000000166D37350 Mode:   IX SPID:52 BatchID:2 ECID:0 TaskProxy:(0x00000001644C6598) Value:0xa30c4980 Cost:(0/0)                                                                                                        
10/04/2013 17:07:40 spid4s                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
10/04/2013 17:07:40 spid4s      Node:2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
10/04/2013 17:07:40 spid4s      KEY: 6:72057598466916352 (2700f60ea813) CleanCnt:2 Mode:RangeS-U Flags: 0x0                                                                                                                                                                                
10/04/2013 17:07:40 spid4s       Grant List 0:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
10/04/2013 17:07:40 spid4s         Owner:0x00000003C6C44980 Mode: RangeS-S Flg:0x0 Ref:0 Life:02000000 SPID:52 ECID:0 XactLockInfo: 0x0000000166D37388                                                                                                                                     
10/04/2013 17:07:40 spid4s         SPID: 52 ECID: 0 Statement Type: DELETE Line #: 1                                                                                                                                                                                                       
10/04/2013 17:07:40 spid4s         Input Buf: Language Event: (@p0 int,@p1 int,@p2 int,@p3 varchar(16),@p4 char(4))DELETE FROM [dbo].[Table] WHERE ([ColumnID] = @p0) AND ([2ColumnID] = @p1) AND ([3Column] = @p2) AND ([4Column] = @p3) AND ([5Column] = @p4)                    
10/04/2013 17:07:40 spid4s       Grant List 2:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
10/04/2013 17:07:40 spid4s       Requested By:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
10/04/2013 17:07:40 spid4s         ResType:LockOwner Stype:'OR'Xdes:0x0000000162F99350 Mode: X SPID:82 BatchID:2 ECID:0 TaskProxy:(0x00000001638A4598) Value:0xf9381180 Cost:(0/0)                                                                                                         
10/04/2013 17:07:40 spid4s                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
10/04/2013 17:07:40 spid4s      Victim Resource Owner:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
10/04/2013 17:07:40 spid4s       ResType:LockOwner Stype:'OR'Xdes:0x0000000162F99350 Mode: X SPID:82 BatchID:2 ECID:0 TaskProxy:(0x00000001638A4598) Value:0xf9381180 Cost:(0/0)
```

and here is the graph from profiler

[image]

and here is the Execution plan

[image]

Original XML with redacted information for 'People' Table

```
<deadlock-list>
 <deadlock victim="processf7a868">
  <process-list>
   <process id="process42e718" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="OBJECT: 6:1629964883:0 " waittime="10781" ownerId="66865028" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2013-04-10T17:07:16.827" XDES="0x166d37350" lockMode="IX" schedulerid="1" kpid="3720" status="suspended" spid="52" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" transcount="2" lastbatchstarted="2013-04-10T17:07:30.170" lastbatchcompleted="2013-04-10T17:07:30.163" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="" hostpid="1908" loginname="" isolationlevel="serializable (4)" xactid="66865028" currentdb="6" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="106" sqlhandle="0x0200000033ce8c2b2096f1641075275d5409c725104fdbc0">
DELETE FROM [dbo].[People] WHERE ([PeopleID] = @p0) AND ([CompanyID] = @p1) AND ([Age] = @p2) AND ([BinaryColumn] = @p3) AND ([PIN] = @p4)     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@p0 int,@p1 int,@p2 int,@p3 varchar(16),@p4 char(4))DELETE FROM [dbo].[People] WHERE ([PeopleID] = @p0) AND ([CompanyID] = @p1) AND ([Age] = @p2) AND ([BinaryColumn] = @p3) AND ([PIN] = @p4)    </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="processf7a868" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 6:72057598466916352 (2700f60ea813)" waittime="4375" ownerId="66866310" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2013-04-10T17:07:30.380" XDES="0x162f99350" lockMode="X" schedulerid="3" kpid="4380" status="suspended" spid="82" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" transcount="2" lastbatchstarted="2013-04-10T17:07:30.410" lastbatchcompleted="2013-04-10T17:07:30.400" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="" hostpid="3524" loginname="" isolationlevel="serializable (4)" xactid="66866310" currentdb="6" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="106" sqlhandle="0x0200000033ce8c2b2096f1641075275d5409c725104fdbc0">
DELETE FROM [dbo].[People] WHERE ([PeopleID] = @p0) AND ([CompanyID] = @p1) AND ([Age] = @p2) AND ([BinaryColumn] = @p3) AND ([PIN] = @p4)     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@p0 int,@p1 int,@p2 int,@p3 varchar(16),@p4 char(4))DELETE FROM [dbo].[People] WHERE ([PeopleID] = @p0) AND ([CompanyID] = @p1) AND ([Age] = @p2) AND ([BinaryColumn] = @p3) AND ([PIN] = @p4)    </inputbuf>
   </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
   <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="1629964883" subresource="FULL" dbid="6" objectname="SERVER.dbo.People" id="lock2a163c280" mode="SIX" associatedObjectId="1629964883">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="processf7a868" mode="SIX"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process42e718" mode="IX" requestType="convert"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </objectlock>
   <keylock hobtid="72057598466916352" dbid="6" objectname="SERVER.dbo.People" indexname="PK_People" id="lock2a8b03d80" mode="RangeS-U" associatedObjectId="72057598466916352">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process42e718" mode="RangeS-S"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="processf7a868" mode="X" requestType="convert"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
  </resource-list>
 </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

Answer (score 6):

> Mode:RangeS-U

Range locks indicate SERIALIZABLE isolation level. Are you using plain [`new TransactionScope()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dbrowne/using-new-transactionscope-considered-harmful)? Unless you really really really want serializable isolation (which is never the case...)  consider reducing the isolation level to something more manageable, start from read committed.

> Mode:SIX

This is an **entire object** Shared lock (the `S` in `SIX`). The UPDATE could not had acquire it as it is, given the selectivity of the predicate `[ColumnID] = @p` and the primary key constraint on `ColumnID`. It must had been acquired by a previous scan on the whole table in the same transaction, and again we see a very high isolation level (at least repeatable, most likely again serializable).

First advice: post the deadlock XML, **always**. Do not post some picture of it, [is useless](https://rusanu.com/2010/05/12/the-puzzle-of-u-locks-in-deadlock-graphs/). The XML contains critical information we would like to see (like, trivial example, the isolation level used...).

Second advice: post what *else* is the transaction doing before issuing the UPDATE.

Last: review your isolation level. Read the linked article about [`new TransactionScope()` considered harmful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dbrowne/using-new-transactionscope-considered-harmful). Always use read committed, unless very very very clear requirement state you need higher isolation levels. [SQL Server 2005 already offers row version based isolation levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/administrator/ms345124%28v=sql.90%29), investigate moving to it.

Comment: I am unable to post the entire XML without sanitising so I thought that would be enough infomration.

Comment: The XML has lots of useful info. But I think in your case the problem is evident.

Comment: Thanks for posting the XML. As I suspected: `isolationlevel="serializable (4)"`. You have some SELECT in the transaction, prior to the UPDATE, that locks the entire table (`SIX`), likely due to lack of indexes (table scan). Can't propose a fix w/o knowing what that SELECT does. None the less moving to READ COMMITTED or SNAPSHOT would be highly advisable (even after fixing the missing index).